# Reading multiple strings from stdin

Tags: c, string, input, scanf

I am writing a very simple code where the input will be like:

1. First line will have number of strings user will enter. Eg:2
2. Print the string

   ```
   char str[20];   
   int TC=0;
   scanf("%d",&TC); //get number of strings
   while(TC!=0){ //read all the strings and print
       fgets(str,19,stdin);
       printf("%s\n",str);
       TC--;
   }
   ```

The code takes N-1 input strings from user rather than N.

Comment: I bet this is a duplicate of all the other `scanf` questions. TL;DR: Rule 1: Don't use `scanf`. Rule 2 (experts only): Don't use `scanf` for user input.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: @melpomene And how else is he supposed to read an int in ANSI C?

Comment: @PSkocik See the second link above (basically `fgets` + `atoi` or whatever).